# Rectangular columnar transposition encryption method

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to get my string into columns without using arrays to become encrypted but don't know how to proceed without using an array please help:

I need to get them to this:

```
3 1 2
S E L
L A L
L S T
O C K
S N O
W
```

Sample output:

generated key: 213

Enter a secret message you wish to encode: 
sell all stocks now

Encrypted message: EASCNSLLOSWLLTKO

My current code:

```
    int num1 = (int) (1+ Math.random() * 3);
    int num2 = (int) (1+ Math.random() * 3);
    int num3 = (int) (1+ Math.random() * 3);


    while (num1 == num2 || num2 == num3 || num1 ==num3) { 
            num2 = (int) (1+ Math.random() * 3);
            num3 = (int) (1+ Math.random() * 3);
    }

    String key = num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "";
        System.out.println("Generated key: " + key);

    System.out.println("Enter a secret message you wish to encode: ");
    String message = input.nextLine();

    String withoutspace = message.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    String capitalMessage = withoutspace.toUpperCase();
```

Basically I can get column1 by doing this:

```
String row = cap.charAt(0) + "" + cap.charAt(3) + "" + cap.charAt(6)+ "" + cap.charAt(9) +"" + cap.charAt(12)+"" + cap.charAt(15)+"";
```

but I need to do a loop for each column to get every third letter no matter how long the word is.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Initiation of variables 
        String string1 = ""; 
        String string2 = "";
        String string3 = "";

        //loop for first string
        for (int i = 0; i < cap.length(); i+=3){
             string1 += (cap.charAt(i) + ""); 
            }
        //loop for second string
        for (int j = 1; j < cap.length(); j+=3){ 
             string2 +=(cap.charAt(j) + "");

            }
        //loop for third string
            for (int k = 2; k < cap.length(); k+=3) {
                 string3 +=(cap.charAt(k) + "");    
                }

            //Prints out the encrypted message based on which key is given
        if(key.equals("123")) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + string1 + string2 + string3);
        }else if(key.equals("132")) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + string1 + string3 + string2);
        }else if(key.equals("213")) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + string2 + string1 + string3);
        }else if(key.equals("231")) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + string2 + string3 + string1);
        }else if(key.equals("312")) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + string3 + string1 + string2);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + string3 + string2 + string1);
        }
```